# Parsing json to list using dart

Tags: json, parsing, dart

I'm facing  a challenge parsing json to list.

I'm expected to return: ['Ada', 'Blaise']
But I'm returning: [['Ada', 'Blaise']]

What should I consider?

```
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  var lista = (nimet('{"nimet":["Ada","Blaise"]}'));
  print(lista);
}

nimet(jsonMerkkijono) {
  var data = jsonDecode(jsonMerkkijono);
  var lista = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var tieto = data['nimet'];
    lista.add(tieto);
  }

  return lista;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code misses a lot of types and I don't know why you have the for-loop. I have rewritten the code which now returns what you want:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final lista = nimet('{"nimet":["Ada","Blaise"]}');
  print(lista); // [Ada, Blaise]
}

List<String> nimet(String jsonMerkkijono) {
  final data = jsonDecode(jsonMerkkijono) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  final lista = data['nimet'] as List<dynamic>;
  return lista.cast<String>();
}
```